# Is there a way to go to another page and at the same time go to an id in the middle of that page

Tags: html, css, angular

I want at the navbar link to go to an page and I want to go to a exactly id of that page (eg. in the middle of the page)

I tried:

```
<a href="home#id" class="nav-link text on-hover"></a>
```

where home is my page and id is my id, and it not working.

If i do just

```
<a href="home" class="nav-link text on-hover"></a>
```

it goes to the page but not to my id on that page

I tried to find this answer some times and nothing lol.
Can anyone help? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that `home` is just a folder that when you enter its name, it shows you the index file. If you want to show a specific part of the page, you should write your code as such ( You should write the id name after the name of the own file not its folder name ) :

```
<a href="home/index.html#id" class="nav-link text on-hover"><a>
```